# STM32F4-Discovery GPIO Always High

Tags: stm32, gpio, stm32f4-discovery, iar

I am doing some work with an STM32F4-Discovery board, and I am trying to get some simple usage out of the GPIO Pins.  However there is a weird problem I am having, that I don't know how to fix.

I am using IAR Embedded Workbench as my IDE, and for some reason the only GPIO Pins I seem to be able to enable are those on the B-Bus.  If I go to enable a pin on any of the other buses and go to set the pin high and low, the volt meter I have hooked up doesn't register anything.

Additionally, there are a few pins on the board that seem to be stuck at a high voltage, which seems weird to me.  Some pins were outputting ~3V before I had even enabled them, or set them high.  Are these pins broken?  Or is there a way to set them low?  Attempting to enable the GPIO Pin and setting it low has not worked for me, so I am unsure of what to do here.

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and a concrete list of pins you've tested and found stuck low/high.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it has been **abandoned with critical information missing** for over a year and as a result is unanswerable by anything other than guesses.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you configure the pins properly

```
> {
    RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOB, ENABLE);
    GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStructure;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin =   GPIO_Pin_0 |
                            GPIO_Pin_1 |
                            GPIO_Pin_2 |
                            GPIO_Pin_3 |
                            GPIO_Pin_4 |
                            GPIO_Pin_5 |
                            GPIO_Pin_6 |
                            GPIO_Pin_7;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_OUT;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_OType = GPIO_OType_PP;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_DOWN;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_100MHz;
    GPIO_Init(GPIOB,&GPIO_InitStructure);
}
```

Source: [Using I/O ports on STM32](https://www.rapitasystems.com/blog/using-io-ports-on-the-stm32-f4-discovery)

Then write to the port. You could have also burned the pin out or ESD'ed the pin, try a few different ports\pins.

The STM32F's usually configure their ports as [high-Z on wakeup/reset](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/28531/what-is-the-common-pin-configuration-upon-microcontroller-reset), with a high impedance meter its possible to measure anything without setting the pin to a determined output. If you put an external 20k pulldown to ground and still measured 3.3V then I'd believe your meter.

Comment: Yeah, I added the 20k pull down to the Pins where I was measuring ~3V without enabling them, and I am still measuring that 3V on my meter.

Comment: if you use `OTYPE_PP` (push-pull) then you don't need configure `PUPD_DOWN`

Answer (score 1):

Some pins have alternate functions for the JTAG and SW interfaces. JTAG pins are *pulled up* or *pulled down* at reset. To use those pins you have to configure the `AFIO_MAPR` register, or define a macro according to compiler.